# SDL2 opengl link error on Windows

Tags: opengl, sdl, linker-errors

I want to use SDL2 with OpenGL on Windows / Visual Studio 12

My source code includes SDL_opengl.h and compiles fine (it is using functions like glBindBuffer(), glGenBuffers()...)

I have added the following dependencies to the linker input: SDL2.lib;SDL2main.lib;opengl32.lib

However, the link fails with error:
    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glBindBuffer@8

And a few more of those.

Other functions like glEnable() and glClear() do link with no problem.

Any idea why?

Should I use GLEW?
If this is the case, why would glBindBuffer(), glGenBuffer(), ... be declared in SDL_opengl.h?

Comment: Yes, you need GLEW or GLee to get access to functions which weren't part of the original OpenGL release.  `opengl32.lib` exports are... less than comprehensive, to say the least.

Comment: Works fine with GLEW indeed, thanks! Is this linker problem specific to SDL on Windows then?

Comment: All the major platforms use extension functions.  Windows allows static linking OpenGL 1.1 only, Mac does 2.0 I hear, and Linux is 2.x, but the newest stuff requires extension loading of some kind.

Comment: GLee makes it really really easy though (but use the version in svn, not the "release")